# How can I get the TF2 logs to show Steam IDs?

Tags: team-fortress-2, server-administration

Previously my TF2 log showed Steam IDs when players connected or when I issued the "users" command.

Now it's only showing usernames without the Steam ID. Is this a change in the log format or is there a configuration setting to show Steam IDs?

Comment: Maybe you've lost connection to the Valve servers in some way?  Been a while...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `status` directly into the server console.

That'll give you a list of people with their:  ping, ID#, packet loss, IP, connection status and Steam ID.