# Is there an option/plugin that shows a player's Steam ID upon exit?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

I was wondering if there was a configuration option, or plugin that showed a player's Steam ID upon exit.

I'm having issues with a particular player who disrupts the server, then immediately leaves and rejoins with a different name.

In case, you were wondering, the server I had in mind on installing the plugin on is a Jailbreak server, if that helps at all.

Comment: Is this information not shown in the console of the server?

Comment: When the player connects it should list information about them. Try this answer: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102500/how-can-i-get-the-tf2-logs-to-show-steam-ids

Answer (score 1):

Theres a SourceMod plugin called [Connect Announce](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=77306), it allows for customizable chat messages to be broadcast to all players, or just admins, on connect/disconnect.

Its default disconnect message for all players is formatted as `{PLAYERTYPE} {GREEN}{PLAYERNAME} {DEFAULT}<{LIGHTGREEN}{STEAMID}{DEFAULT}> from country {GREEN}{PLAYERCOUNTRY} {DEFAULT}({LIGHTGREEN}{PLAYERCOUNTRYSHORT}{DEFAULT}) disconnected from IP {GREEN}{PLAYERIP}{GREEN}reason: {DEFAULT}{DISC_REASON}`

I'd make it shorter but as you can see, it is quite customizable.